# How to check/uncheck a list of checkboxes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, redux, react-redux

I have a `room` page and in that page I have a list of sensors attached to that room, those sensors can be selected using a checkbox, like so:

```
<div className="checkboxRowContent">
  {sensors.map(s => {
    return (
      <div className="checkboxElementWrapper" key={s.id}>
        <label htmlFor={`sensor${s.id}`}>
          <div className="checkboxLabel">
            <Link to={`/sensors/edit/${s.id}`}>{s.name}</Link>
          </div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id={`sensor${s.id}`}
            name="sensorId"
            value={s.id}
            checked={s.roomId === values.id}
            onChange={handleCheckbox}
          />
          <span className="checkbox" />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

the problem is - this approach prohibits me from unchecking the checkbox (so if in db that sensor is attached to that room - that's it). How could I rewrite this so that I can check/uncheck this checkbox?

Comment: [A similar question came up yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499813/react-js-storing-an-array-of-ids-in-state).

Answer (score 4):

in the class you must have state for that,

a sample would be somewhat like this

```
export default class yourComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    checkedBoxes: []
  }

  handleCheckbox = (e, s) => {
    const checkedBoxes = [...this.state.checkedBoxes];
    if(e.target.checked) {
      checkedBoxes.push(s)
    } else {
      const index = checkedBoxes.findIndex((ch) => ch.roomId === s.roomId);
      checkedBoxes.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.setState({checkedBoxes});
  }


  render() {

    return(
      <div className="checkboxRowContent">
      {sensors.map(s => {
          return (
            <div className="checkboxElementWrapper" key={s.id}>
              <label htmlFor={`sensor${s.id}`}>
                <div className="checkboxLabel">
                  <Link to={`/sensors/edit/${s.id}`}>{s.name}</Link>
                </div>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={`sensor${s.id}`}
                  name="sensorId"
                  checked={checkedBoxes.find((ch) => ch.roomId === s.roomId)}
                  onChange={(e) => handleCheckbox(e, s)}
                />
                <span className="checkbox" />
              </label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

A state, `checkedBoxes` for getting all selected checkboxes.

A handler `handleCheckbox` for handling checkbox clicks,

Comment: Using `push` in this example is not good because [you are mutating the state](https://jsfiddle.net/tcp7gd0w/).

Comment: @Andy I can change `const checkedBoxes = this.state.checkedBoxes;` to `const checkedBoxes = [...this.state.checkedBoxes];` it will do, right?

Answer (score 2):

You have `handleCheckBox` and a controlled component. We don't see what you do in the event handler but when it's controlled, you can check it by altering your sensors array (if in state/props) so `s.roomId === values.id` will be true.

If you don't want it to be controlled, you can probably use `defaultChecked` which will let you work with it in a different way.

see https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: I was thinking about changing the state, but how can I set a default state for a list of infinitie amount of checkboxes?

Comment: if you want to check/uncheck all sensors then perhaps you need to design a hook that lets you override the room id - if your sensors is in state or props, you can loop them and do whatever. see https://codepen.io/DimitarChristoff/pen/ZXMKKb

Comment: keep in mind in this example if your sensor data changes you need to have more lifecycle methods and propagate props to state.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Books = props=>(

<div className='form-group'>
    <label>{props.book}
        <input type='checkbox' name={props.name}  className='form-check' onChange={props.onChange} />
    </label>
</div>
)

class Total extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.onChangeCheck = this.onChangeCheck.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state={
        checkBoxes: [],
        books:[]

    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/book/').then(resolve=>{
        console.log(resolve.data.data);
        this.setState({
            books:resolve.data.data
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
}

onChangeCheck(e){
    console.log(e.target.name)

    if(e.target.checked){
        const array =  this.state.checkBoxes;
        array.push(e.target.name)
        this.setState({
            checkBoxes:array
        })
    }else{
        const array =  this.state.checkBoxes;
        const index = array.indexOf(e.target.name);
        console.log(index)
        array.splice(index,1);
        console.log(array);
        this.setState({
            checkBoxes:array
        })
    }
}

onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.put("http://localhost:8080/books/getTotal/",this.state.checkBoxes).then(resolve=>{
        console.log(resolve)
        alert(`Total price of books ${resolve.data}`);

    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })

}


render(){
    return(
        <div className='card'>
            <div className='card-header'>
            </div>
            <div className='card-body'>
                <form className='form' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                    <div className='form-group'>
                        {
                            this.state.books.map(object=>(
                                    <Books name={object._id} book={object.name}  onChange={this.onChangeCheck} />
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <button type='submit'  className='btn btn-success'>Get Total</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Total;
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.