# Auto checked checkboxes based on array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

newbie in react here may I request for your assistance on below?

How do I populate or checked/unchecked checkbox based on Array's result

I want to display allSystems checkbox with ID 1,3=checked and ID 2=unchecked upon modal pop-up for Edit

I tried below code but no luck, it just display 3 checkboxes(allSystem) but no checked based on(selectedSystem)

```
const [allSystems, setallSystems] = useState([]); // List of systems ex [{ID: 1, SYSTEM: "SYSTEM1"},{ID: 2, SYSTEM: "SYSTEM2"},{ID: 3, SYSTEM: "SYSTEM3"}]
const [selectedSystem, setselectedSystem] = useState([]); //List of selected IDs from allSystems ex ["1","3"]

        {
                    allSystems.map((val, i) => {
                    return(
                        <FormControlLabel 
                            key={i}
                            control={
                                <Checkbox 
                                    name={val.ID}
                                    color = 'primary'
                                    value = {val.ID}
                                    checked={selectedSystem.includes(val.ID)} //also tried checked={selectedSystem.includes(String(val.ID))}
                                    onChange={handleSingleCheckAffectedSystem}
                                />
                                    }
                                label = {val.DEP_ALIAS}
                        />
                    )
                })}
```

Hoping for your understanding

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520775/how-to-check-uncheck-a-list-of-checkboxes-in-react i hope u will get u r answer.

Comment: My code is almost the same, but it's just displaying allSystems without any checked from the selectedSystem

Comment: Please verify the value of selectedSystem.includes(val.ID) once. You can add a console log before return inside arrow function.

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan console.log(selectedSystem.includes(val.ID)) returns false. I'm confused.

Comment: Please debug further, check the valud of each individual variables involved in that expressions. Values may be not update as expected. Either val.ID is wrong or selectedSystem is containing somethiong else

Comment: I made it checked={selectedSystem.includes(String(val.ID))} and it's now okay. Thank you @Karthikeyan

Answer (score 0):

```
checked={selectedSystem.includes(String(val.ID))}
```